# Can we change [camera-identification] to [equipment-identification]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

I've edited [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83970/35348) and was trying to add an identification tag. As it turns out, we only have [camera-identification](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera-identification) and nothing else. As this tag only has 5 questions, I suggest we change it to `[equipment-identification]` and use that as a tag for all identification questions.

As for the mentioned question, it asks to identify compatible cameras, but the real question asked is to identify the lens. While [camera-identification](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera-identification) might be a proper tag for this question due to the way it was asked, I think the suggested name change would be a good thing to do anyway, as not every identification question asks for a compatible camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is helpful to have distinct tags for camera identification and lens identification. There's no rule that says both such tags can't be attached to the same question when appropriate.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. I just stumbled across an identification question neither about camera nor lens, so I created the tag [tag:equipment-identification] as a general tag for such questions. Feel free to create one for lenses if appropriate. (or other specialised tags)